# Why does \tcolorboxenvironment set the savedelimiter key?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

The [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) command `\tcolorboxenvironment{<envname>}{<keys>}` is defined as

```
\newcommand{\tcolorboxenvironment}[2]{%
  \AddToHook{env/#1/before}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[{savedelimiter={#1},#2,wrap@environment,%
      code={\def\tcb@end@tcolorboxenvironment{\end{tcolorbox}}}}]%
  }%
  \AddToHook{env/#1/after}{%
    \tcb@end@tcolorboxenvironment%
  }%
}
```

So it sets the `savedelimiter` key to `<envname>`. Why does it do this?

In the code, I see only two places that it is used: in `\tcblower`, and in `\tcb@addcontentsline` for lists of tcolorboxes. The use case for `savedelimiter` given in the documentation is for defining a new environment with the `tcolorbox` environment that can do things with the lower box:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{mybox}[1]{%
\tcolorbox[savedelimiter=mybox,
savelowerto=\jobname_bspsave2.tex,lowerbox=ignored,
colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
title={#1}]}%
{\endtcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{My Example}
Upper part.
\tcblower
Saved lower part!
\end{mybox}
Now, the saved part is used:
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!5]
\input{\jobname_bspsave2.tex}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

But I don't think this can work with `\tcolorboxenvironment` since it wraps the `<envname>` in `tcolorbox` so if you try to grab the `\tcblower`, for example, it will error because it's also grabbing `\end{<envname>}`. Indeed, this errors:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcolorboxenvironment{quote}{}

\begin{quote}
upper
\tcblower
lower
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

I also don't see how `\tcolorboxenvironment` can be used with `\tcblistof` since the latter needs a corresponding `list inside` key which can only be called in one of the built-in `\newtcolorbox`-type commands.

Am I missing a use for `savedelimiter` here, or is it actually unnecessary in the definition of `\tcolorboxenvironment`?

Comment: Surely you've been here long enough to know not to post code fragments. Also, this kind of question is probably best asked of the developer rather than here on the site.

Comment: @AlanMunn :) Indeed, I suppose I figured this wasn't the kind of question where someone needed to run the code themselves but that was misguided. For the second part of your comment, before bothering the developer I wanted to see if I was overlooking something obvious. If the [github page](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox) had a "Discussions" section I would feel less awkward asking there but it does not. Contrary opinions are welcome and I could be convinced to close/delete